# Updating tables in Sage

Tags: sql, accounting

I'm currently getting an error from doing a simple update function.

```
Begin Transaction
Update dbo.SLCustomerAccount
Set SYSCreditBureauID = 'the ID Number'
Where (CustomerAccountNumber LIKE 'A%')
Rollback Transaction
```

This works fine when stating one account but as soon as you add the like it comes up with a message stating that the string or binary data would be truncated from a Procedure.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense that that update statement would cause the issue directly. Any triggers on `SLCustomerAccount`?

Comment: Hi Martin thank you for the quick response, there is a trigger on the SLCustomerAccount which basically says if adding a new account number then put this into another program database.

Comment: So does that trigger fire on `UPDATE`? If so what is the code for that?